# app enter catch section when trying to connect database

Tags: android, sqlite

I don't want to make longer the question. I'm a newbie.

LogCat is [here](http://pastebin.com/qBXWAuB7)..
Database Class [here](http://pastebin.com/6yNqGgMt).. Also activity's code below..

```
bDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                boolean ok = true;

                try {

                    db.open();
                    String data = etData.getText().toString();
                    db.addThat(data);
                    db.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ok = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (ok) {
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(Main.this);
                        TextView tv = new TextView(Main.this);
                        tv.setText("Conrats! That's done!");
                        d.setTitle("Ok!");
                        d.setContentView(tv);
                        d.show();
                    }
                }
            }
```

App enter inside of catch section. Waiting for helps..

Comment: What does the `db.open()` do? And what exception is the code throwing?

Comment: @Darwind look at the database class

Comment: Yeah I just saw that ;-)

Comment: So it's in the insert statement. It's throwing a `NullPointerException` - check if your `String data` is actually set from the `EditText` field.

Comment: @Darwind Yes It's EditText. There is no problem. I can print 'data' variable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized ourDatabase on the class Database before using it. That is causing the null pointer exception.

Change the method open to

```
    public void open() throws SQLException {
            ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```